# Problem with converting string to integer

Tags: arrays, c, string

(I am very new to both coding and C.)

I want to check if the nr one string in "string argv"  is one or more decimals and if it is convert it to an integer. I think I may need to iterate over the string but so far this code is not working. It says segmentation fault.

This is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main (int argc, string argv [])
{

    //check command line
    if (argc == 2)
    {
        printf("success");
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Usage: ./caesar key.");
    }

    //validate number
    if (isdigit (argv[1]))
    {
        int x = atoi(argv[1]);
        printf("I is now %i\n", x);
        return 0;
    }

    if (isalpha(argv[1]))
     {
        printf("Usage: ./caesar key\n");
        return 1;
    }
}
```

Comment: Which line generates the error and what is the exact error message text?

Comment: The condition `array is bigger than two` is not standard C. Use `strlen()` with the name of your array and compare the result with the number `2` by the mean of this binary operator: `>`

Comment: 'some of it is in pseudocode, because that part works', well, you will need to do more to convince an experienced developer than just make a claim.  Compiler error messages are often misleading and generate an error on a,line far removed from the real error location.

Comment: @MartinJames thanks for replying. I have changed it a bit and its compiling but it does not print out the value of the integer. I just get "segmentaton fault"

Comment: You should get a warning for calling `isdigit(argv[1])` -- `argv[1]` is a "string", that is a pointer to the first element of a char array, but `isdigit` expects a character (as `int`), so you'll need `isdigit(*argv[1])` or `isdigit(argv[1][0])`.

Comment: @MOehm I see. but I want to put all of the characters in that 1th string in a integer. Do I need to iterate over it? I tried that but it did not work. I got the wrong number...

Comment: If you are using CS50, then you need to write `#include <cs50.h>` in order to use the `string` data type.

Comment: The function `isdigit` tests whether a single character is a digit. If you want to test whether all characters in a string are digits, you must loop over the string. The function `atoi` tries to convert the whole string to a number. (The loop is in the function itself.) There is another function, `strtol`, which converts a string to a `long`. It has better possibilities for error checking.

Comment: @rootkonda OP does not claim _string_ as  a type.  The C library does define _string_.  OP is using this C term correctly.

Comment: @Reinstate Monica - It is just a comment/remark I did not mean he claimed it. Second of all, C library has string.h header file and contains some useful str functions but as far as I know you cannot define a data type itself as string.

Comment: @rootkonda  "c has string data type" and "define a data type itself as string" are not relevant ot OP's question.

Comment: Ok, so you are saying using atoi does not requier the iteration loop?

Do I need the isdigit then? or could it be something like (again, super new to C);  
if (argv[1] == 2)
    {
        int x = atoi(argv[1]); 
}

Comment: @MOehm I tried iterate over the string and check via "isdigit" if the character was an digit. And then assign all the characters to an integer. But that did not work. I got a wrong message: incompatible integer to pointer conversion passing 'char' to parameter of type 'const char *' 

for (int i= 0; i < strlen(argv[1]); i++)
{
    if(isdigit (argv[1][i]))
    {
        int x = atoi(argv[1][i]);
        printf("I is now %i\n", x);

Comment: No, that's wrong again. Now you try to call `atoi` on a character, but you need to call it on a string. Also, don't convert inside the loop where you test. The test could go like this: `i = 0; while (isdigit(s[i]) i++;` Now test `s[i]`. If it is the `'\0'` at the end of the string, you have a number. Now convert with `atoi(s)`. Only that yu use `argv[1]` instead of `s`.

Comment: [Here](https://ideone.com/yuM6oV) are three different ways to test and convert an integer. Enjoy!

Comment: Thanks everyone! That part is solved :)

Answer (score 1):

`main` function takes (int argc, char *argv[]) parameters. argv is a pointer to pointer and argv[1] is a pointer to a char array too. You should send a character to `isdigit` and `isalpha`, not a pointer. You get a segmentation fault because of this probably.

Answer (score 1):

> check if ... string ... is one or more decimals and if it is convert it to an integer.

`isdigit (argv[1])` --> `argv[1]` is a pointer to a *string*.  `isdigit(int ch)` expects a single character, not a pointer.  Enable all compiler warnings for fast feedback.

---

A direct approach uses `strtol()`

```
bool test_and_convert(const char *s, long *valptr) {
  errno = 0; // set to 0 to later detect overflow
  int base = 10;
  char *endptr;
  long *valptr = strtol(s, &endptr, base);
  if (s == endtpr) {
    return false; // No conversion
  }
  if (errno == ERANGE) {
    return true; /* or false, OP's choice here */
    // *valptr is clamped to LONG_MIN or LONG_MAX
  }

  // Detect trailing non-numeric text if desired
  if (*endptr) {
    return false;
  }

  return true;
}
```

A plodding approach akin to OP's.

```
bool test_and_convert_plodding(const char *s, int *valptr) {
  // Best to access characters as unsinged char for `is...()` functions.
  const unsigned char *us = (const unsigned char *) s; // 
  
  // Maybe skip leading spaces
  while (isspace(*us)) us++;

  unsigned char sign = *us;
  if (sign == '-' || sign == '+') {
    us++;
  }

  // Accumulate digits
  unsigned found = false;
  unsigned uvalue = 0;
  while (isdigit(*us)) {
    found = true;
    // Overflow detection code needed here is TBD
    uvalue = ulvaue*10 + (*us - '0');
  }

  if (!found) {
    return false; // No digits
  }

  // Maybe skip trailing spaces
  while (isspace(*us)) us++;

  // Maybe detect non-numeric junk at the end.
  if (*us) return false;
  
  // Overflow detection code needed here is TBD
  *valptr = (sign == '-'  && uvlaue > 0) ? (-(int)(uvalue - 1) - 1) : (int) uvalue;
  return true;
}
```